# calling Application.method(String s) method from index.scala.html

Tags: java, scala

I'm struggling to link different parts of `scala/java` application together

in my `controllers.Application` I have :

```
public static Result getInfo(String id) {
...
}
```

in `routes` I have :

```
GET     /Info/:id   controllers.Application.getInfo(id: String)
```

now what I want to do is to use such structure as part of my webpage

for example  in `index.scala.html I want to say -->

```
<div myid="info">
@helper.form(controllers.Application.getInfo(@id))
</div>
```

this gives me the following error :

```
illegal start of simple expression
@helper.form(controllers.Application.getInfo(@id))  //error highlights the @ sign before id
```

I'm not quite sure what I should put into `index.scala.html` could someone explain what I am doing wrong please

Comment: Remove the second `@` near id.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a very useful error message...

I noticed one thing right off the bat, though: in your `routes` file you have `getPersonalInfo` but in your `Application` class you have `getInfo` for the method name.

Comment: sorry, i tried to change the names to simplify the readings, I forgot that, i'll update my question right away